# How to read incoming SOAP request in php

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I want to read the SOAP request which is coming from a .NET WinForms application.

The request is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body>
 <HotelPricesRQ xmlns="http://zelsoft.ru/">
  <HotelPricesRequest>
    <Requestor Login="ZLS" Password="DE52F10D5089096E5D83CA559153D64824AAB0B4" />
    <Conditions>
      <Condition CityID="0" CountryID="0" HotelID="0" AccommodationID="0" RoomCategoryID="0" RoomTypeID="0">
        <Created Begin="2013-10-31T00:00:00" End="2013-10-31T23:59:00+04:00" />
      </Condition>
    </Conditions>
  </HotelPricesRequest>
 </HotelPricesRQ>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So how to get the Requestor's Login, Password and the Creattion Begin Date?
I have actually build the response, we've test it and when they send me the request they got the response. I'm just sending the responce without reading the request, but I have to read it and log in diffrent users and send different response. So a real example with the request I've posted above will be much much appreciated.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/soapserver.soapserver.php

Comment: I've read all the php.net manual for SOAP, but there is no real example of how to do that, or at least I didn't get it.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php is full of examples... read user' comments.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why I didn't write the solution I got back then for reading the request,
but here it is, in case someone needs it:

```
$soap_request = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

Then I just parse it with the PHP XML Parser Functions like so:

```
$parser=xml_parser_create();
xml_parse_into_struct($parser,$soap_request,$request_array);
xml_parser_free($parser);
```

Now you have the data in the `$request_array` as an array.

You can also use The `SimpleXMLElement` class to get the data from the request.